# Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, google-maps

[REE]eRROR LOG IN CONSOLE[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiCvb.png)

Google map doesnt load even after inserting api key

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0cxW.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a `InvalidKeyMapError` as an error in your implementation, it means that the API key included in the script element that loads the API is not found as per [Error Messages documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#:%7E:text=Premium%20Plan%20authentication.-,InvalidKeyMapError,-Error). Please make sure you are using a correct an API key.

For visibility, here's the `script` tag for your Maps JavaScript API where your API key should be included:

```
<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Your API key should be appended after the `key` parameter. *[Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Loading_the_Maps_API)*

Answer (score 0):

First you have to have a maps api valid token, making a new project and get the credentials, from

https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/credentials

You have to add your credit card, for validation. They will take from you $0.00, from your account, to validate that is you and not a robot script.

If you don't get a valid maps key you will get in browser console

```
Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError
```

And in project ReactGoogleAutocomplete:

`npm i react-google-autocomplete`

Create in FE in .env this:

`REACT_APP_GOOGLEPLACES_API_KEY=your_valid_maps_key`

Restart the project after you modified the .env file.

Inside your component, where you use Google Maps MyComponent.js, add in top

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactGoogleAutocomplete from "react-google-autocomplete";
const config = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLEPLACES_API_KEY;
```

And inside this component

```
const config = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLEPLACES_API_KEY;
const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
```

Then add this Maps component inside return()

```
<ReactGoogleAutocomplete
  className="form-control m-2"
  placeholder="Location"
  apiKey={config}
  onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
    setLocation(place.formatted_address);
  }}
  style={{ height: "50px" }}
/>
```

In the bottom of this component you can see the result.

`<pre>{JSON.stringify({location }, null, 4)}</pre>`